# Give Bootstrap 3 columns vertical margins

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to know, what would be the usual approach to give [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/) columns a margin. I likely don't want to hack Bootstrap CSS and wonder if I simply should apply additional classes, or if there is another good way?

Example:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 v-margin">
      <!-- some content -->
   </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.v-margin {
   margin: 25px 0;
}
```

Also I have read a few times that a padding is preferred due to, for me unknown, reasons. Can anyone can give a quick advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose a custom css in this case I will apply with a classname on the `.row` item if you want the same separate on the columns like this:

```
<div class="row v-margin">
   <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div>some content</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-6">
     <div>some content</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Then with css apply `padding`:

```
.v-margin > div {
  padding:0 20px;
}
.v-margin > div:first-child {
  padding-left:40px;
}
.v-margin > div:last-child {
  padding-right:40px;
}
```

Check this **[BootplyDemo](http://www.bootply.com/PKASxN8OkC)**

---

Now why choose `padding`?

Because Bootstrap works with the property [`box:sizing:border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) and fixed `width` for the columns.

- If you use `margin` you will break the float layout because margin are aside the width value.
- Instead when you add `padding` it's included on the fixed width value with the box-sizing property.

Comment: thanks again, but, how would padding affect some properties like background images. As in my OP mentioned, I need a vertical gap between elements within the same row. And a padding would not apply to `background: url()`. So would I use the margin then?

Comment: No @supersize keep using padding and if you want to apply a background then use it on an inner element liek I do on the example ... check the backgorund blue is applied on the inner div element

Comment: alright I see, but as a last question. Is there a reason why you are applying the class to the parent and then use child selectors ( `>` ), instead of directly apply the class to each element. I assume this is just because of demo purposes?

Comment: Ah the reason can be @supersize that if the space will be equal insted of add the class for each item is just one for the parent ...  If you want to add more columns later you don't need to apply that.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap have jumbotron and wells those have large padding inside them

- [http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#wells)
- http://getbootstrap.com/components/#wells

and if we use them then we have to override their background because they use colors in their backgrounds . but they are not exact suitable for large containers.

**now we will go to the exact answer below**

i dont think so its bad idea because some times boostrap dont provide every thing you need .  in order to meet your requirement its normal because you are adding your behaviour alongside bootstrap but its good when you handle it also as bootstrap working

**for example according to devices if you control flow of the margin its fine.**

```html
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .v-marg-small { margin: 5px 0;} 
  .v-marg-normal { margin: 10px 0;}
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .v-marg-small { margin: 10px 0;} 
  .v-marg-normal { margin: 15px 0;}
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
 .v-marg-small { margin: 15px 0;} 
   .v-marg-normal { margin: 20px 0;}  
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
 .v-marg-small { margin: 20px 0;} 
   .v-marg-normal { margin: 25px 0;}
}
```

on the other hand while handling your content

1. if you completely down your div and div have background or border
   then by giving margin will look like first box .
2. if you have background color or image or border of div then
   padding will look like second box. 
   for better understanding i have attached image .

[image]